# How to use datadriven tests from one scenario to another scenario which have different URLs in karate framework

Tags: karate

I have 2 Scenarios and I am providing data in one of the scenario via data driven tests i.e. using Examples in the end of that scenario1. Now I want to understand is there any way that we can pass those same data to different scenario2( this scenario is getting called inside of scenario1).

Below is my code to understand things better:

```
Scenario Outline : 1st Scenario
*** URL "XYZ url"**
* request {id : <id>, name: <name>}
* method POST
* response = $.response
* def res2 = call read(@Scen2)
* def response2 = res2.response
* match response == response2
Examples:
|id||name|
|1|Tripti|
|2|Tan|

@Scen2 @ignore
Scenario : 2nd Scenario
*** URL "ABC url"**
* request {id : <id>, name: <name>}
* method POST
* response = $.response
```

So basically I want to know that the data passed from examples in scenario 1, how can it be used for scenario 2?
I want the scenario to run one by one and then match data for one particular data set at a time.

Please don't close this question. As it is different question entirely. The URL in both scenarios are different. Which changes the problem.
One of the scenario is also getting called by another

Comment: Hey Peter! My question is different than the one you have mentioned. please go through it once and help me in finding the solution.

Comment: is this resolved?

Comment: Hey! It is not resolved. Can u help?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shreyansh791/5061c31c8121ff2748fb9110e7c0ad28